# Getting weird results in TensorBoard in the Profile Tab

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-tpu

I am kind of getting really fishy results for my TensorBoard Profile calculations. It seems that my Host idle time (not sure what host this is reffering to?) is really high which is super bad, but my TPU idle time is 0% which is super good. Also what do I have to do to measure the step time? I am a bit lost here.

[image: Tensorboard]

Comment: Does anything show up in the trace viewer? I would also try collecting for a longer time period with --duration_ms

Comment: What kind of model are you running on the TPU? If this is not a TPUEstimator model, did you define a global_step? (That could account for step time issues).

Comment: From what I remember it showed some stuff in the trace viewer, but I will have to check again. What time-period would you recommend? @michaelb

Comment: It is a TPUEstimator model. Do I still have to define the global_step somewhere explicitly? @liamdalton

Comment: The profiler will drop excess events over 1 million, so I would start with something like --duration_ms=60000

Comment: Oh I see thanks that worked. It seems though that 60000 is the maximum duration. What if a step time is lets  say 30 sec. Then you just get the time for the first step right? Or I can assume the step time is constant? Also if you write this down as a seperate answer I can approve it :) thanks for the help @michaelb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results with no step time graph can be an indicator that the step time is longer than the default collection duration (2 seconds).

To increase this run capture_tpu_profile with the option

```
--duration_ms=60000
```

To capture metrics for a 60 second period.

One way to check if this is the issue is to look in the trace viewer for the numbered steps up the top.

TPU step times are normally well less than a second so if 60 seconds is still not long enough its likely an issue with the input pipeline. The trace viewer should show you which threads are taking up time, and you can follow this guide to optimize the input pipeline.

https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/datasets_performance

Another option is to capture the profile after the model has run through a few steps, the first few steps tend to be slower due to cache's building up.